# If I collect my resources, will it reduce any loss from attacks?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Currently, I am having a hard time collecting resources.

I am constantly attacked every time I'm without a shield. The losses of gold and elixir are huge: I can lose 50-80% of my resources in 2 attacks.

I always though that picking the resources would reduce my losses, but I'm no longer sure of this.

If I pick my resources, will it reduce any loss from attacks? Or there is absolutely no difference?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of: [What happens when I get attacked by another player?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/93965/4797), [What determines how much of my resources are available for an opponent to steal?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/153071/4797), [How do they compute the Gold and Elixir that can be looted?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/167246/4797)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a diference... That depends on TH (Town Hall) level.

**In STORAGE:**

- From levels 1-5, a 20% is lootable.
- Then, from levels 6-10, descend 2% per level, so at lvl 10, only 10% 
  is lootable.

**In MINES / COLLECTORS:**

- 50% lootable at any TH level.

Finally, also your uncollected war loot can be stolen from your Clan Castle:

**In Clan Castle:**

- From levels 1-5, 10%.
- From 6-10, descends 1% per level, till 5% lootable at lvl 10.

So, there is a significant diference (up to 40% depending on TH level). It's a lot better to collect resources.

Source: http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids

Comment: Wow, my google-fu sucks... Even though the question was marked as duplicated, there wasn't such a detailed answer as yours. I wish more people upvote this. None of the others provided this kind of information. Thank you so much!!! And now, excuse me while I pick my resources.

Comment: You are right, I've been checking that asnwers and are not helpful at all...

Comment: I agree. They barely answer anything at all. Lets see what the meta has to say about this.

Comment: My answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/228082/68492) is even more detailed than this answer. I'm not sure you actually checked the other questions in their entirety.